# How to resolve ** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3) *** error: can't allocate region error

Tags: ios, objective-c

HI in my app I am downloading files from server and total file size is more than 9GB.After download 1GB data app is crashing and showing the error as ** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3) *** error: can't allocate region. Can any one helps me how to resolve this issue.

```
+(void)base64Decode:(NSData *)fData writeToFile:(NSFileHandle *)fHandle
{
    unsigned char inBuffer[4] ;
    unsigned char outBuffer[3] ;

    NSRange part ;
    part.location = 0 ;
    part.length = 1 ;

    NSMutableData *oData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init] ;
    BOOL bInProgress = YES ;
    int i ;
    int total = 0 ;

    while ( bInProgress )
    {
        inBuffer[0] = inBuffer[1] = inBuffer[2] = inBuffer[3] = 0 ;
        outBuffer[0] = outBuffer[1] = outBuffer[2] = 0 ;

        for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ;  )
        {
            if ( [fData length] > part.location )
            {
                [fData getBytes:inBuffer+i range:part] ;
                part.location++ ;
                if ( ( inBuffer[i] == 0x0d ) || ( inBuffer[i] == 0x0a ) )
                    continue ;
                else
                    i++ ;
            }
            else
            {
                bInProgress = NO ;
                break ;
            }
        }

        //      if ( i != 4 )
        //      {
        //          NSLog ( @"Less\n" ) ;
        //      }

        int unexpect = 0 ;

        for ( int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++ )
        {
            if ( ( inBuffer[j] >= 'A' ) && ( inBuffer[j] <= 'Z' ) )
            {
                inBuffer[j] -= 'A' ;
            }
            else
            {
                if ( ( inBuffer[j] >= 'a' ) && ( inBuffer[j] <= 'z' ) )
                {
                    inBuffer[j] -= 'a' ;
                    inBuffer[j] += 26 ;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ( ( inBuffer[j] >= '0' ) && ( inBuffer[j] <= '9' ) )
                    {
                        inBuffer[j] -= '0' ;
                        inBuffer[j] += 52 ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ( inBuffer[j] == '+' )
                        {
                            inBuffer[j] = 62 ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ( inBuffer[j] == '/' )
                            {
                                inBuffer[j] = 63 ;
                            }
                            else
                            {
#ifdef DEBUG
                                NSLog ( @"fHandle Unexpected char: %c: %x\n", inBuffer[j], inBuffer[j] ) ;
#endif
                                unexpect++ ;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        i -= unexpect ;

        int len = (i * 6) / 8 ;

        if ( ( i * 6 ) % 8 )
            len++ ;

        total += len ;

        outBuffer[0] = ( inBuffer[0] << 2 ) | ( ( inBuffer[1] & 0x30 ) >> 4 );
        outBuffer[1] = ( ( inBuffer[1] & 0x0f ) << 4 ) | ( ( inBuffer[2] & 0x3c ) >> 2 );
        outBuffer[2] = ( ( inBuffer[2] & 0x03 ) << 6 ) | ( ( inBuffer[3] & 0x3f ) );

        [oData appendBytes:outBuffer length:len] ;

        if([oData length] > 1024*10)
        {

            NSError *error;


        BOOL dataWritten=[self writeData:oData toFileHandle:fHandle error:&error];

            NSLog(@"dataWritten %hhd",dataWritten);

            if(oData)
            {
                [oData release];
                oData = nil ;
            }

            //[oData release];
            oData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init] ;
        }

    }
    //fwrite([oData bytes], 1, [oData length], fHandle) ;
    //[fHandle writeData:oData] ;

      NSError *error;

    [self writeData:oData toFileHandle:fHandle error:&error];



    if(oData)
    {
        [oData release];
        oData = nil ;
    }   //  NSLog ( @"Total written: %d\n", total ) ;
}






+(BOOL)writeData:(NSData *)data
     toFileHandle:(NSFileHandle *)fileHandler
            error:(NSError **)error
{
    @try
    {
        [fileHandler writeData:data];
    }
    @catch (NSException *e)
    {
        if (error != NULL)
        {
            NSDictionary *userInfo = @{
                                       NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Failed to write data",
                                       // Other stuff?
                                       };
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyStuff" code:123 userInfo:userInfo];
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}



Here fileHandler is NSFileHandle *pdfPathHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
```

Comment: You're running out of memory. But you haven't shown us any of your code, so we can't possibly guess why.

Comment: It looks like @duskwuff is right. You are buffering the file in memory, so you are running out of memory.

Comment: Why don't you just use a download task and download direct to disk? That way, the file is not held in memory at all, and you don't need any extra code - the system does the download for you.

Comment: So can you please let me know what are the changes I have to do in my code.

Comment: The code you've supplied doesn't actually download anything! Show us *all* of the relevant code.

Comment: Hi duskwuff I updated my question can you please check it once.

Comment: @NareshG Firstly do you understand *why* your app is running out of memory?

Comment: Hi Droppy May i know what are the possible reasons for this condition.

Comment: This looks like the same issue you're having in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021908/how-to-handle-low-memory-warning/28022264?noredirect=1#comment44430567_28022264 if the files you're downloading are too huge then you need to write to disk in chunks, if they are too large to be base64 decoded then you need to read and decode them from disk in chunks

Comment: Can you please let me know where i have to do these changes in base64decode method. Please