# How to handle low memory warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

In my app I am getting low memory warning after few files download.I stops current download process. Even after that also app crashes and I am assuming that app crashes due to low memory issue. Can any one please let me know how can I free up memory in running app.

Comment: What is your app downloading that is so big?

Comment: Hi in app I am downloading pdf files,video files.Files size is 2.7 gb sometimes it's more than that.

Comment: I've posted an answer, although it's a bit odd that your app is downloading such big files, are they app resources such as images and video?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're downloading the files straight to memory. That will be an issue because you wont have enough memory to download the entire file.

The strategy you need to take is, as you download the file continue to write chunks of it out to disk, freeing up memory in doing so.

If you are using NSURLSession there is a parameter you can use to do this for you with little effort. Please post your code for in depth help.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. Can you please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884607/how-to-resolve-mach-vm-mapsize-8388608-failed-error-code-3-error-can?noredirect=1#comment44203086_27884607. Here i mentioned my problem and code also there.